# error: octave_base_value::save_ascii(): wrong type argument 'object'

Tags: octave

How can I fix to save, write command in octave?

Import_Data

error: octave_base_value::save_ascii(): wrong type argument 'object'

```
DATASET.TSERIES = csvread(’MR_AER_DATASET1.csv’);
DATASET.LABEL   = {’DATES’,’T_PI’,’T_CI’,’m_PI’,’m_CI’,’APITR’,’ACITR’,’PITB’,’CITB’,’GOV’};
DATASET.VALUE   = [  1,       2,     3,     4,    5 ,    6 ,     7 ,     8  ,   9 ,    10 ];
DATASET.UNIT    = [  0,       2,     2,     2,    2 ,    2,      2 ,     1  ,   1 ,    1  ];

save (’DATASET’, ’DATASET’);
```

Comment: Looks like saving/loading `classdef` objects has not been implemented yet, according to [this discussion](https://octave.discourse.group/t/error-octave-base-value-save-ascii-wrong-type-argument-object/719).